# Docker WORKDIR - on my machine or the container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What context does the `WORKDIR` keyword in a Dockerfile refer to? Is it in the context I run `docker build` from or inside the container I am producing?

I find myself often putting `RUN cd && ...` in my docker files and am hoping there's another way, I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you try `WORKDIR` out? What problem are you facing?

Comment: I found that the docs were not explicit enough for me and was seeking clarification, as @markybb41 has provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is inside the container.

Taken for the Dockerfile reference site https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

> The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile. If the WORKDIR doesn’t exist, it will be created even if it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction.

So rather than adding `RUN cd && ...` you could do:

```
WORKDIR /path/to/dir
RUN command
```

Comment: It's also so if you `docker run` something it runs in that directory which is especially handy if you're opening a shell to test.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I didn't find the docs spectacularly clear.

Comment: "The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile."  LIterally DOES NOT specify whether the WORKDIR path is on the local machine or in the container. For a beginner, this documentation is 100% ambiguous.  Another answer says "All paths in a Dockerfile, except the first half of COPY and ADD instructions, refer to image filesystem paths." This is a critical piece of information that a beginner asking these questions would not have.

Answer (score 5):

*All* paths in a Dockerfile, except the first half of `COPY` and `ADD` instructions, refer to image filesystem paths.  The source paths for `COPY` and `ADD` are relative paths (even if they start with `/`) relative to the build context (the directory at the end of the `docker build` command, frequently the directory containing the Dockerfile).  Nothing in a Dockerfile can ever reference an absolute path on the host or content outside the build context tree.

The only difference between these two Dockerfiles is the directory the second command gets launched in.

```sh
RUN cd /dir && command1
RUN command2
```

```sh
WORKDIR /dir
RUN command1
RUN command2
```

Comment: Are `cd` calls persistent throughout multiple `RUN` calls then? I was under the (perhaps mistaken) impression that they were not.

Comment: They’re not – each `RUN` command happens in a new shell (in a new container even).  In the two examples `command2` will get launched from different directory.  (`RUN cd ...` in isolation is a no-op; so are `RUN export ...` and `RUN . ...`.)

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

`WORKDIR` sets the directory inside the image and hence allows you to avoid `RUN cd` calls.